# clearInterval doesn't seem to be clearing

Tags: jquery

I have a function which has an interval in it, which I want to clear/reset each time the function is run.

The function is called again in the interval, but also on button press so when the interval gets to the start again if the button is also pressed to call the function, it starts to run it multiple times.

```
function call() {
    var live_chat_interval;
    clearInterval(live_chat_interval);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/section/tickets',
        data: {
            "action": "ticket_details",
            "ticketnumber": '<?php echo $ticket["ticketnumber"]; ?>'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'live_chat') {
                live_chat_interval = setInterval(function() {
                    console.log("refresh");
                    //call();
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `setInterval` here, use `setTimeout` instead. Also put your timeout ID outside the function so it could persist between the function's calls:

```js
let timeout;

function call() {

  clearTimeout(timeout);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/section/tickets',
        data: {
            "action": "ticket_details",
            "ticketnumber": '<?php echo $ticket["ticketnumber"]; ?>'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'live_chat') {
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log("refresh");
                    call();
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```